Carousel vertical tipo stack usando react-native-reanimated y react-native-gesture-handler
Llevo muchos dias intentando realizar (sin lograrlo) una animacion para una app con expo 50 que cumpla los siguientes requerimientos: 1. Cuando el usuario desliza hacia arriba pasa a la imagen siguiente, cuando el usuario desliza hacia abajo no pasa nada. 2.La animacion de la imagen sera la siguiente: Saldrá de abajo hacia arriba y se pondra por encima de la imagen anterior. 3. La animacion sigue el deslizamiento del usuario con su dedo hacia arriba, si el usuario deja de deslizar por debajo de la mitad de la pantalla, la imagen animada cae como por efecto de gravedad y se oculta. Si el usuario deja de deslizar por encima de la mitad de la pantalla, se finaliza la animacion y la imagen siguiente se vera por completa en la pantalla. 6. Estas reglas se aplican para todas las imagenes en este carousel vertical
